# loading usercontrols dynamically - postback issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, postback, page-lifecycle

Im trying to load a usercontrol dynamically on a aspx page however it works but i get postback issues?? I have a image button on usercontrol which I want to show a image however when i do click on button the page refreshes and does not show image?. I have a placeholder on aspx page and backend code i have this :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {      

     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
            Control uc = Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/Mycontrol.ascx");
            placeholder1.Controls.Add(uc);

     }
 }
```

Do i need to do something in page_preinit or page_init ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic controls added to the page must be added on every postback, not just the first one.  Remove the `!IsPostBack` condition.  Secondly, they have to be added during init or preinit, because that way, viewstate will be captured and restored properly (ASP.NET restores viewstate between init and load events).

Comment: Guys, check this one http://geekswithblogs.net/chrishan/archive/2007/03/27/109988.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You should always reload the user control on the Page_init on each post back.

Answer (score 1):

Give the control an ID and also load the control in Page_init

```
uc.ID = "your id";
```